# On Image click Dropdown value should change to the Image name in Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I having two different divs, in one div I having Images and in second Div i having another dropdown box,
1)  Hey are four images in first div, when ever you click on image, drop down should change to the name of the image,
Eg: 1st image Title is “First Image”, if you click on Image dropdown should to “first-image”.

Values are coming from different json values and I put it in for loop.

```
<div >
            <div>
                <button *ngFor="let filter of result" type="button" >
                    <div id="imagepathtext" (click)="showSelected(event)">
                        <img  src= "{{filter.imageurl}}">
                    </div>
                    <div >{{filter.name}} </div>
                    <div> 
                        <span>{{filter.count}}</span> Funds
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
```

This is drop down Div,

```
<div >
                <div >
                    <select>
                        <option [value] = "all" >
                            All Asset Classes
                        </option>
                        <option [value] ="filter.name" *ngFor="let filter of result" >
                            {{filter.name}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Please let me know the answer, Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post an example JSON of each filter object?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. I mean provide plnkr or jsfiddle link or provide json.